# Communicating with Linux kernel developers

Tags: linux-kernel

What is the correct protocol for communicating with Linux kernel developers with a question or potential bug in a particular section of code?

I can do `git blame -e` and email the person who last touched the code, but they may not be the best person to look into it, and if they are on vacation (or too busy to respond) it could be a black hole.

I can ask on `linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org`, but that looks like [a very high volume mailing list](https://lkml.org/lkml/last100/) and I'd be concerned about the email being lost in the noise or bothering too many people about a very specific question.

I can ask on this site, but if it's a highly specific question about code that isn't easily understandable, it is unlikely I'd get a good response.

Is there an officially recommended way to determine who is the best person to ask about a section of Linux kernel code?

Comment: `get_maintainers.pl` is a good first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [get_maintainer.pl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/get_maintainer.pl) script to see who's responsible for the specific file in question. Use it like so from the `linux` dir:

`perl scripts/get_maintainer.pl [OPTIONS] -f <file>`

The [kernel newbies mailing list](https://kernelnewbies.org/MailingList) can also be a good place to start.

Comment: I would add `--git-min-percent=67`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: the [`get_maintainer.pl`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/get_maintainer.pl) script does include:

> Using "`--roles`" or "`--rolestats`" with `git send-email --cc-cmd` or any other automated tools that expect only `["name"] <email address>` may not work because of additional output after `<email address>`.

That should be more robust with Git 2.16.x/2.17 (Q1 2018): Instead of maintaining home-grown email address parsing code, ship a copy of reasonably recent Mail::Address to be used as a fallback in '`git send-email`' when the platform lacks it.

See [commit d60be8a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d60be8acab06c34886338cbf98f7628284705979) (08 Jan 2018) by [Alex Bennée (`stsquad`)](https://github.com/stsquad).
See [commit c8f9d13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8f9d13dc6ddcb6c9e22584324c18b7d74e772ea) (08 Jan 2018), and [commit bd869f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd869f67b93b36e27405db5e288ee82f3a49051a) (05 Jan 2018) by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 897de84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/897de845e62ddccba5310057b64d568bc3d4e182), 23 Jan 2018)</sup>

> ### `send-email`: add and use a local copy of `Mail::Address`
>
> We used to have two versions of the email parsing code.
>
> - Our [`parse_mailboxes` (in Git.pm)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0e544bf6cdde69987f92c2ea59ef4016bda0f62d/perl/Git.pm#L889-L891), and `Mail::Address` which we used if
>     installed.
>     Unfortunately, both versions have different sets of bugs, and changing the behavior of git depending on whether `Mail::Address` is installed was a bad idea.
>
> A first attempt to solve this was [cc90750](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc9075067776ebd34cc08f31bf78bb05f12fd879) (`send-email`: don't use
>   Mail::Address, even if available, 2017-08-23, Git v2.14.3), but it turns out our
>   `parse_mailboxes` is too buggy for some uses.
>   For example the [lack of nested comments support **breaks `get_maintainer.pl`** in the Linux kernel
>   tree](https://public-inbox.org/git/20171116154814.23785-1-alex.bennee@linaro.org/).
>
> This patch goes the other way: use `Mail::Address` anyway, but have a
>   local copy from CPAN as a fallback, when the system one is not
>   available.
>
> The duplicated script is small (276 lines of code) and stable in time.
>   Maintaining the local copy should not be an issue, and will certainly be
>   less burden than maintaining our own parse_mailboxes.
>
> Another option would be to consider `Mail::Address` as a hard dependency,
>   but it's easy enough to save the trouble of extra-dependency to the end
>   user or packager.